# Why am I consistently getting "insufficient privileges" when trying to install BlueStacks?

Tags: windows, windows-8, administrator

[image]

1. I've run the installer as administrator.
2. I've went to the Start Menu folder, the Programs folder, and Windows Live folder all individually and edited the Security tab so that ALL users have 100% access to the folders, despite the permissions being recursive anyway.

I'm just not understanding. I'm on Windows 8 and can NOT get past this step for this installer and several others.

Comment: When you say all users have 100% access to the folders does that include the SYSTEM account? Make sure that specific account has 'Full Control' on the folder listed in the error message.

Comment: @GlennStevens could you add this as an answer? SYSTEM account not having privileges (LOL if you ask me) is most common reason for errors like these.

Answer (score 0):

try copying this folder on desktop and delete original folder change permissions of copied folder and copy back.

[This](http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH155446) might be the reason

[detailed instructions to solve problem](http://helpx.adobe.com/creative-suite/kb/error-1303-installer-insufficient-privileges-1.html)

Comment: I tried both of those links and neither worked. also, the wording of your answer was almost impossible to understand. it makes no sense at all, at least not to me. could you be a bit more clear, and maybe add working links?